# Passing SQL Server Name of SSIS Job to package variable

Tags: sql-server, configuration, ssis, package

I am trying to figure out a way that I can pass the SQL Sever Name an SSIS Job is running on, to a variable within a package.

Basically, which ever Server this Job is running on, will be passed to the ServerName property in an Ole DB Connection in the package so the data is loaded into that server.

I have been looking at documentation on package configuration, and I feel like it would be in the environment variable section.  However, I do not think any of the listed "environment variables" are the server name.   I have Googled this issue, and searched on StackOverflow for problems, but I cannot seem to find this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to reuse a package across servers without reconfiguring the connection manager? If so, the question has been asked here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111587/how-to-make-the-server-name-dynamic-in-an-ssis-package

Comment: @rwking as far as I can tell that is not a solution to the problem I am asking.  I don't just need to set connection strings dynamically.  I specifically need the servername that the current Job is running on.  I can pass a servername from a sql table, from a different ole db source that is hardcoded.  But that is not what I am looking for.  Thank You.

Comment: So you want to set the servername to a package variable?

Comment: It is possible that it is the solution, and I need to create the System Environment Variable that contains the server name, but there is no real explanation how to do this

Comment: Can you give some more detail around what you're ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: we want to have an ole db destination where the servername property is a variable that is set to whatever the server name is where the ssis job is located.  It's definitely a dynamic connection string, but we don't have any set values, nor do those values exist in any user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by using a script task, and C# code to grab the Machine Name, or IP address of the machine running it.

Dts.Variables["User::ServerName"].Value = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a few different approaches, but I think you can accomplish this with a simple Execute SQL Task.

1. Create a new Execute SQL Task
2. Under General -> SQL Statement, enter your query `Select @@SERVERNAME as ServerName` in the "SQLStatement" field
3. Under General -> Result Set, choose "Single row"
4. Under Parameter Mapping, Enter your variable (create one if you don't have one) User::ServerName in Variable Name, "Input" as direction, 0 as Parameter Name, and -1 as Parameter Size
5. Under Result Set, enter "ServerName" for your Result Name and type the variable in Variable Name
6. Click OK

Give that a go and see if it accomplishes what you want.

Comment: This was not able to accomplish what I want because an Execute SQL Task requires an Ole DB Connection string to execute a query.  Even if it's just querying a system table.

Comment: Dts.Variables["User::ServerName"].Value = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName();  

This C# function gives me the Host Machine Name, which is often the  Server Name (Although I think the Database Engine instance could be different)