# Parameter for Database server in SSIS

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a SSIS package(say `LOADCON`) created in server `SDEU1123` to load some data from text file to table `CONTENT001`.

Now I have the same table(`CONTENT001`) in another servers as well `SDEU1124` and `SDEU1125` and I want to load these table using the same package `LOADCON` using some parameter. I just need to change the value of the server using this parameter.

I have tried creating a parameter using `PROJECT.PARAMS`. But I'm not sure how to use this and where should I refer this.

I have checked this [How to make the server name dynamic in an SSIS package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111587/how-to-make-the-server-name-dynamic-in-an-ssis-package). But this seems to be too old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didnt mention where you wanted to change the value.

Here are the options that I know;

If you want to implement it when you develop your SSIS package;

- go to connection managers.
- choose your connection.
- go to the properties window and press expressions.
- on the property expressions editor choose connection string and press [...] on the expression field.
- open variable and parameter and choose your relevant PROJECT.PARAMS ( you need to create two for this scenario)

[image]

If you want to change it on the server - after deploy (SSISDB catalog);

- you can use "environment variable" [Setup Environment Variables in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4810/setup-environment-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/)
- config the package on the catalog and change the parameter value.
- config the step on the job that runs the package and change the parameter value.

Comment: Thanks. I want to change it in SSIS package only. Where should i use  these parameters(`PROJECT.PARAMS`) after clicking [..] and also how it will dynamically change when i use this in other server.

Comment: @Omega let me understand, you develop the package on the server? (the solution folder exists on the server himself?) and you want to copy the solution folder from one server to another - and each server, the connection string value will refer to the current server?

Comment: yes, the created package exists in the server itself. And yeah i want to copy the package created in one server to another server. Also, the connection String value will refer to that server. Here i want to know, When i copy the package to another server, where should i change the servername? in project.params? If so, i would like to know how changing the `project.params` affect the server name in the OLB DB destination?

Comment: I think that the best way to do this is by deploying your project from one server and config the parameter connection string value in each server himself, nevertheless, inside your connection parameter you can use system variable that calls @[System::MachineName] that show the local Machine Name or just use period - **Data Source=@[System::MachineName];Initial Catalog=yourDB;Provider=SQLNCLI11.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;**