# Parameterizing Database Connection in SQL Server Integration Services

Tags: ssis, visual-studio-2017

I have been struggling with the creation of testing environment for my existing [SSIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Integration_Services) solution (Visual Studio) and I can't figure out the right approach.

My current solution is based on a production server; let's call it PROD_SERVER.
All existing packages are connected to it.
I have another SQL server; let's call it DEV_SERVER where I want to test my packages.
This is an old solution. We are still developing and maintenance it, and previous developers haven't created any such additional environment. I assume they simply test it on PROD :)

I want to somehow switch between servers in Visual Studio to execute packages, but I don't have any idea of how to determine any potential solutions or even how to create testing scenarios. I already found some articles, but I do not see any similarities.

Just to mention, packages are not so complicated, but they use many connection managers at once so parameterizing a particular database is not the right way (I could be wrong of course).

I copied an existing solution and changed all connection managers to DEV, but I would like to have it in my place.

Additional resources already studied for this case:

- *[Parameterizing Database Connection in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.sqlshack.com/parameterizing-database-connection-sql-server-integration-services/)*
- *[Setup Environment Variables in SQL Server Integration Services](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4810/setup-environment-variables-in-sql-server-integration-services/)*
- *[Parameter for Database server in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59465215/parameter-for-database-server-in-ssis)*

I copied an existing solution and connected to another server.

Comment: _packages are not so complicated, but they use many connection managers at once so parameterizing a particular database is not the right way_ What do you mean by this? Parameterising connection managers is pretty much the _only_ way.

Comment: @Nick.Mc I mean that a package executes on 2-3 databases so 2-3 connection managers are used in one process. It starts from staging area on one database and moves further with transformations to another. I want to change a server somehow in VS not to test it on PROD.

Comment: @wp78de Apologies, no. I don't know how to use it further.

Comment: I shared a video link that walks through the steps and where to find it in the UI. That should get you there youtube.com/watch?v=-YBvfaygWO8

Comment: @wp78 oh...got it now. I simply need to change the value of the server in the connection string manually and execute the package. That works. Not super fancy, but for the project maintenance, fine. I also struggled to simply import the same project to the solution, change connection strings and have everything in one place.

Comment: Glad to hear. The beauty of a parameter is that you can change it as part of the step configuration on a job. So, you could use the same package in multiple steps for different connections by changing the ConnectionString parameter value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various ways to achieve this. The most straightforward approach is to parameterize the connection your package is using.  You can do this with a project level (screenshot) ConMgr connection (created on the project tree) or on the package level (you probably already have a SQL connection there) in the connection manager panel of the Control Flow view.

Right-click the connection there, select Parameterize...
You probably want to configure the ConnectionString

[image]

This will expose the connection string as a parameter that can be adjusted in the configuration of the deployed package

[image]

Comment: This video might be helpful too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YBvfaygWO8